# Why do some electronics have two power/ground pins?

Tags: power, pcb, ground

I was looking at the BMP280 temperature/pressure sensor schematics on KiCAD, and I saw that it has two power pins, and two ground pins. Why is that?

Please let me know if more information is needed on this part.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GND pins are largely the same, they are duplicated mostly because there is no good reason not to.

The VCCIO pin supplies the digital I/O, and the VDD pin supplies the analog hardware that performs the measurement. These should be decoupled separately, so the noise introduced by the digital protocol does not disturb the measurement.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons to have two even more power pins. Intenal blocks of the chip are separated so they can use separate pins, for example one pin for powering noisy digital logic and one for powering sensitive analog circuits, so that the user of the chip can externally provide as much as filtering as needed to keep the noisy parts affecting the sensitive parts.

For this chip the purpose of supply pins is said in the datasheet.

This chip separates the internal supply voltage VDD from the VDDIO voltage used to communicate with the microcontroller. They can even be different voltages, and one power supply is allowed to be turned off to save power.

The ground pins may also each relate to certain supply node such separate grounds for analog and digital circuitry, but they might just be paralleled to have better grounding, as it results into lower series resistance and inductance.

Answer (score 0):

Although schematic are,logic and not physical, it seems the author of the datasheet wants you to use a common ground connection to both pins shared by the ground path of the capacitor grounds, rather than directly between the closest path.

Ground is what you define as 0V so you don't want to share digital noise currents in an analog path and the quality of that 0V ground up to you.

They would be connected internally but the designer wants you to also connect them externally so that the cap. surge currents for logic switching do not influence Vref and analog results if routed differently.

Everything has some resistance and ESR and parasitic ESL inductance which affects SNR quality at max frequency.

[image]

Datasheet found [here](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/products/environmental-sensors/pressure-sensors/bmp280/)